# Debugging Firebase Authentication in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

My sign in with firebase authentication completes successfully. I am using signInWithPopup. It returns a blank screen but does not break the flow. However after logging in, a message appears in my console. The message is :
A boolean is being passed as a fourth parameter to window.open. This is not used and may cause an exception in a future release.
How do I handle this exception?
The second part of the question is what data in response(that we get in promise from firebase sign in with popup) correlates with the above mentioned exception? Is it a completely different problem or does it have anything to do with the blank popup? Thank you in advance. If more information is needed to solve the problem, kindly say so.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a newly introduced bug with Firebase and one of its dependencies. I suggest rolling Firebase to a previous and consistent version for Firebase and its sister modules

Source:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4988